# PHP within HTML not working using Flask

Tags: php, python, html, flask

I have just recently started playing around with Flask and have no previous html/php experience, so please forgive me if this is naive!

I'm trying to use some php within an html file to improve a webapp I've built, but cannot even get the simplest test case to work. For example, take a test case from [this site](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/):

--test_app.py--

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask('flask_test')

@app.route('/')
def test():
    return flask.render_template('test.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

--templates/test.html--

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul> 
<?php for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<li>Menu Item <?php echo $i; ?></li> 
<?php } ?>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

--expected output--

```
Menu Item 1
Menu Item 2
Menu Item 3
Menu Item 4
Menu Item 5
```

--actual output--

```
Menu Item
```

If there an inherent incompatibility with Flask? Am I forgetting to include something (either on the python/flask side or the html/php side) that will make it all work together?

Thanks!

Comment: have you try to change your template to test.php instead of test.html?

Comment: hmm, is there any reason to use PHP with flask? as flask already support its own template solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would not use PHP in Flask. If you want some scripting logic in your template, use something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for i in range(1,6) %}
<li>Menu Item {{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question by **Matt Healy** is right.

But looking at your code I seem problem it should be like this

```
<ul> 
 <?php 
    for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){ 
      echo "<li>Menu Item ".$i."</li>"; 
    } 
 ?>
</ul>
```

And make sure you have `.php` as the file extension. Because Php will not run in HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP interpreter does not work the way you want to use it.
You are calling the HTML (template) file from within a flask app, thus not using the PHP interpreter.
You best stick to PHP with supportet templating eg. smarty, or go for Pythonic. Trying mixing the two is a bad idea.