# Flask - Keep checkboxes checked after form submission

Tags: php, python, html, forms, flask

I have a form with questions and checkboxes. I would like to show the checked boxes after the form has been submitted.

```
<form action="/predict" role="form" method="POST" id="prediction_form">
  <p><b>Check the box next to the question</b></p>
  <div class="checkbox">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="1">
    1. question
    ...
```

I searched answers to this question and found that some people use PHP (via [PHP keep checkbox checked after submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12541419/php-keep-checkbox-checked-after-submitting-form)). However, this didn't work for me when I tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="1" <?php if(isset($_POST['q1'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  />
```

I also read from [PHP within HTML not working using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216179/php-within-html-not-working-using-flask) that you shouldn't use PHP with Flask.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you rendering the template?

Comment: Which are you using: Flask or PHP?

Answer (score 0):

PHP and Python are completely different languages (Flask runs on top of Python). Trying to use PHP to improve the functionality of Flask is like trying to use German to improve your French. They are separate and don't work well together.

The answer in [PHP within HTML not working using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216179/php-within-html-not-working-using-flask) is correct. You need to use Jinja2 commands within your .html file.

I would recommend using [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to generate your checkbox instead of doing it yourself.