# Populating dropdown list from text file using php

Tags: php, html, flask

I am trying to populate a select tag in html form with data from text file. I am using php to do it. Please find the code below:

temp.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$filename = 'C:\templates\exam.txt';
$eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

?>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
        <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>
        <select id="value">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
           <?php foreach($eachlines as $lines){
                echo "<option value='".$lines."'>$lines</option>";
            }?>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

exam.txt

```
Req. A + B
Req. B
Req. C
```

But in the dropdown list I am not getting any data. I am expecting dropdown list to show data from text file as select options.

I am passing php file as render template using Flask. Can we use PHP in Flask?

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the content of the text file?

Comment: And maybe you need to escape both usages of `$lines`: `echo "<option value='".$lines."'>".$lines."</option>";`

Comment: @Emaro I have included text file data..

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging. Try adding `print_r( $eachlines );` after `$eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` to see exactly what is being read from your file into your array.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? For example, have you checked what `$eachllines` contains by dumping it?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yea, I checked it.. `$eachllines` is empty..

Comment: Can you put `exam.txt` where the php file is for testing and remove the windows path? Using absolute paths can be a problem. (the `\t` in `C:\templates` makes me nervous).

Comment: Have you tried using a double backslash, like `$filename = 'C:\\templates\\exam.txt';`

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yea I already tried it but no luck.. its same thing.. And also this php file is rendered by flask like `render_template('temp.php')`

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes I tried with double backslash but no changes..

Comment: Are you sure you can use PHP in flask? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216179/php-within-html-not-working-using-flask

Comment: You should have clarified in your question and your tags that you are using Flask

Comment: @PeterKrebs not sure whether we can use PHP in flask.. never tried it.. Sorry, I will tag "flask" in the question. If PHP cannot be used then, is there any other way to populate text file data into dropdown list?

Comment: Well I assume you can supply variables to the template like any template engine allows. Have you checked the documentation? Is this the one? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/